# What is a good NLP library that is able to guess a title for a given paragraph?

Tags: ruby, nlp

For example, if I have the text: (random paragraph taken from a question on Quora)

> The war in SW Asia - The presence of US military forces eases the
>   strains of having more than 100,000 US troops on the ground in SW
>   Asia. Germany is a launching pad for forces going to Afghanistan as
>   well as to bases throughout SW Asia. If the US were to leave,
>   alternate facilities would either have to be leased or built to
>   support whatever complement of forces will remain in Afghanistan and
>   also to support US military actions in the Persian Gulf. This would
>   also cost tens of billions which just aren't there.

The library would be able to determine a suitable title to be something like:

> The war in SW Asia and US Troops in Germany

Is this possible? Is there any library available that is able to do this?

Comment: Maybe you might want to acquire [Summly](http://techcrunch.com/2013/04/22/yahoo-unveils-brand-new-ios-app-including-built-in-summ-ly-summaries/) by offering more than $30 million.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is theoretically possible, but it is a hard problem involving many layers of data processing, and a good backing data set to help bootstrap any machine learning aspects of such a task. It's the kind of project that could involve multiple engineers who are experts in the field working for significant time.

No, there isn't a simple Ruby library for this. Not even one that is a client for a web service that performs the task.

You may want to look at some basic Ruby NLP gems and data sets to get a feel for what is in reach of current code and services. For instance Concept Net: http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu/ *might* be an interesting place to start looking at problems like this - I am not aware of any Ruby wrappers for it, although the JSON format should be simply accessible to Ruby.

Alternatively, if your task is for a commercial project, and you are able to pay a small amount per summary, you might want to consider using a human-powered service like Mechanical Turk, for which there is a Ruby gem: https://github.com/mdp/rturk